# Match 3 sub genre

Tags: terminology

Most match 3 games allow you to swap two items on a grid allowing you to create groups of three or more items.

Dungeon raid allows you to draw a line through three or more similar items to create groups.

To create distinction between the two game mechanics: Are there different match 3 sub-genres and what are they called? And what games uses them?

Cheers

Comment: I don't think "Match-3" is a genre of video games.  If you think otherwise, provide some supporting reference.  Even if it is, I suspect it's a subgenre of something else, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

"Match-3" is actually a subset of the "Tile-Matching" genre. Tile matching is a genre that encompasses games like Tetris, which makes you match tiles in a certain way to score points. Match-3 makes you match 3 tiles in any direction VS making you match tiles in a single line across the playing field, for instance.

Match-3 RPG's or Match-3 Puzzles increase the difficulty by adding in specific benefits or effects depending on which match-3's you do.

[Tile Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile-matching_video_game)
[Supported Game Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Tile-matching_video_games)